# VB excel reloadas causes object disconnected from it's clients

Tags: excel, vb.net

I'm using VB to open an excel file and I'm having trouble with encoding.   Some characters are displayed as garbage.   I discovered that when I open the file with excel then reopen it with utf8 encoding the characters display correctly.  In my VB program when I try to use the reloadas method  the reload appears to work but receive the error "object disconnected from it's clients" error message.

Is there a way I can avoid using the reloadas and open the file using utf8?  If not how can resolve the error I'm getting?

```
        Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(SaveFN)
        xlWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8
        xlWorkbook.ReloadAs(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8)

        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)    'error occurs here
```

thanks.

Comment: This may be a case where using `ActiveWorkbook` is necessary. Try placing `xlWorkbook =xlapp.ActiveWorkbook` after the `ReloadAs` statement.

Comment: Thanks, activeworkbook worked

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to use the reloadas method the reload appears to work but
> receive the error "object disconnected from it's clients" error
> message.

This is because when the Excel reloads the Workbook, the existing Workbook object is destroyed and the reference held by `xlWorkbook` is no longer valid.

Based on the usage of `WebOptions`, the file is probably an Html file.  However, Excel does not expose an open method that takes a file format argument.  This leaves using `Application.ActiveWorkBook` or `Application.WorkBooks` collection as the only means to retrieve a reference to retrieve the Workbook.

```
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(SaveFN)
xlWorkbook.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8
xlWorkbook.ReloadAs(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8)

xlWorkbook = xlapp.ActiveWorkbook ' *** add this statement
Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet = xlWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
```